# Some errors when customizing run-python

Tags: python, debugging

I want to make a complement to `run-python` in `python-mode`. Here is my snippet:

```
(defun dpy-run-python ()
  (interactive)
  (when (python-shell-get-process)
      (delete-process (python-shell-get-process)))
  (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) t)
  (python-shell-send-buffer t)
  )
```

Explain:

Each time when I run `dpy-run-python`，it kill running python shell if any exists, then create a new process at the same window, which looks like:

[image]

However, my code come out error when executing:

[image]

I have read the source code of `python.el`，it seems like some comint protocols between emacs and python shell process, but I have no idea what should I do.

Comment: Maybe running as a dedicated process does it for you? C-u M-x run-python RET - and get prompted for decicated.

Comment: Actually, `run-python` in my snippet with the 2nd para `t` means a dedicated process. And the python shell in image is a dedicated process in fact.

Comment: This is just a guess, but it looks like `run-python` will pass some special arguments to Python when it runs in a new buffer, but not in an existing buffer. Two suggestions: in part 1 you could not only kill the process but the buffer too; or, if you care about the contents of the buffer, there may be a specialized function you have to call instead of `delete-process` to tell python mode that you're starting afresh.

Comment: In order to make sure a running process is killed first, maybe you should not start it as dedicated. Its easier to spot than. Otherwise you need something like M-x list-processes RET.

Comment: @q.undertow Maybe you're right, there may be some potential arguments. And I do want to keep the contents in buffer. I'll try to look for the functions if any exists.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler The process has been killed certainly, and new process has also been created. The problem is when I send codes to it by `python-shell-send-buffer` to that new process, the error occurs as the 2nd image. It may be something wrong in the comint protocol.